# I don't know how to choose the GUI develop tech

Tags: xml, user-interface, qt

I mainly work on C#, and WPF is my first choice when I make desktop software.
But I am lack of C++ experience, and I want to develop some desktop software in C++, now I have some problem with the GUI framework. I'm learning Qt, and compared to WPF, I have much more code to write, I like the XML way to describe GUI. But Qt's XML doesn't have many functions like WPF, and I don't like the new qml.
I heard about lua + xml to make the GUI. It's inspired me, **I think may be I can use python or ruby do the GUI (in xml way), and C++ do the logic, does there any solution?** 
Can somebody give me some links or advice?

Comment: Have you tried using Qt's Designer program for the GUI?  It creates an XML file describing the GUI that you want, and Qt provides the program you need to turn that XML file into code as well.

Comment: I know qt's designer can turn the ui file into an xml file, but I don't like the way qt did.I want a script language like python or ruby to do the gui, and c++ do the logic as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

You say you like declarative UI but you don't want to use QML? What don't you like about it? Have you used it?

Qt + QML will likely be the most convenient way to develop a GUI application in C++.

Comment: I have seen some examples of qml, but it's a little weired I think.I like declarative ui like wpf and flex, I want to find some same way in c++ but with the script language do the gui